Deleting multiples that aren't exact PostgreSQL
I think the issue came when inserting my data, some of the data looks like this:



id
year




1
2000


1
2001


1
2002


2
2000


2
2001


2
2002


3
2000


3
2001


3
2002



Where the intention was for it to look like this:



id
year




1
2000


2
2001


3
2002



Is there a way to fix this without re-doing the table? Or should I delete it and start over?

The rules that you want for the data aren't clear.

If year is  functionally dependent on id like you make it seem, then just drop the noise column year completely (and replace it with a simple computation in the output, possibly in a view).

Hi, and welcome to dba.se. AIUI, you want the .lowest year associated with the lowesr possible id? We require clarity!

From the description it seems that you are trying to fix the data. In your case id should be PRIMARY KEY,  and the year column UNIQUE.
If you just want to select the data use,
WITH distinctYears AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT year
  FROM yourTable
),
orderYears AS (
  SELECT year,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS id
  FROM distinctYears
)
SELECT id, year
FROM orderYears
ORDER BY year ASC


Result
id    year
1     2000
2     2001
3     2002



If fixing the data is your goal , create another table with PRIMARY KEY
CREATE TABLE fixedTable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    year INT NOT NULL UNIQUE -- its up to you if year should be unique or not
);

Insert the data, leave id to automatically be populated
WITH distinctYears AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT year
  FROM yourTable
)
INSERT INTO fixedTable (year)
SELECT year
FROM distinctYears
ORDER BY year ASC;


Result
id    year
1     2000
2     2001
3     2002



See example

It's not clear what the actual rule should be, but if is that year must be id+1999 then:
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE year <> id+1999

would be more than enough (but then one wonders why you have both columns).
Alternatively, if it's not such a simple rule, but there is a 1-1 relationship between id and year, then:
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE (id, year) NOT IN ((1,2000),(2,2001),(3,2002))

could do.
There are also options using another table for the list of valid combination (but if that's the case, then you should instead normalise the data and keep that table and use JOINs when querying.
But not knowing the actual rule, and the amount of data involved, it's impossible to say with any certitude.

Assuming that this is all you want to change, try this
delete from tablename
where (id = 1 and year in (2001,2002))
or (id = 2 and year in (2000,2002))
or (id = 3 and year in (2000,2001))

Use your tablename

What if there are 20+ distinct years ?
